# How to open incognito/private window Chrome By C# Test project automation

Tags: c#, automation, incognito-mode, testproject.io

I am trying to open incognito/private window Chrome by Automation code. I am using C# and Testproject ro run my code.
Does anyone here have any experience with this, can explain to me what I can do? thank you so much

Comment: @Pieterjan No, I don't developing an angular app. Currently I am coding by Visual Studio code, and use C# programming language + testproject

Comment: Do you want it to be incognito when recording too?

Comment: If there is no way to do that, you can try to open standart chrome by Process.Start("chrome path"); after that you can use SendKeys.SendWait("^+(N)"); By the way ^ equals to CTRL and + equals to Shift :) I hope it is useful for you.

Comment: @cbalakus I am using C# and testproject so I do not have Sendkeys to do like that =((

Comment: @Costa No, I just want only perform when I run automation

Answer (score 0):

Try this, make a new job and click "Set Driver Desired Capabilities" (5th button) then make sure to pass "--incognito" in the arguments like this:

```
{
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "version": 83,
    "goog:chromeOptions": {
        "args": [
            "--incognito"
        ]
    }
}
```